# Scrolling to content after a Bootstrap Accordion is opened

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Accordion that has many panels in it. The issue I am facing is if the panel opens off the page the user has no idea that the panel is open and they can scroll down to it.

To solve this I wanted to be able to scroll to the content that is now open so they know that the content is open and it saves them from scrolling to it.

I seem to be running into issues though when trying to attempt this.

This is what my function looks like

```
$('.accLink').on('click', function(){
  if($(this).parent().next('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in')){

  }else{
   //This is where the scroll would happen
  }
});
```

so far I have tried...

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: ($(this).parent().next('.panel-collapse'))
  },500);
```

and

```
$('div').animate({
  scrollTop: ($(this).parent().next('.panel-collapse'))
  },500);
```

I have also tried something like this...

```
function scrollToElement(ele) {
    $(window).scrollTop(ele.offset().top).scrollLeft(ele.offset().left);
}

var element = $(this).parent().next('.panel-collapse').attr('id');
scrollToElement($('#'+element));
```

but neither do anything to the page. it just sits there. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 18):

Rather than a separate click event listener, use Bootstrap's built-in event callback:

```
$("#accordion").on("shown.bs.collapse", function () {
    var myEl = $(this).find('.collapse.in');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(myEl).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

Or, if you want the heading to show:

```
$("#accordion").on("shown.bs.collapse", function () {
    var myEl = $(this).find('.collapse.in').prev('.panel-heading');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(myEl).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Scroll page to show expanded/active accordion on top in page

```
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  var offset = $('.panel.panel-default > .panel-collapse.in').offset().top;
  if (offset > 0) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.panel .active').offset().top - 100
    }, 500);
    // you can chagne 100 value to take distance in pixels from top in page
  }
});
```